# Deploying project which uses CouchDB as db server

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

What are good patterns to working with Couchdb. I would like to know:

- easly way to debug functions in design docs - very important,
- how to write design docs as easly as possible ? - so far I used Futon interface, but  whether it is good practice ? I am looking for project which is currently maintained, like CouchApp or Kan.so ? I think, that Fauxton has better handling multi-line code formation
- is still couchjs developing as Node.js QueryServer ? I think to create global functions in separated files, then add main.js file which would use require to import my all functions. Then in CouchDB local.ini add main.js to QueryServer parameter. I have also installed Node-Inspector, so I think, that would be good solution for debugging the code ?
- What should I avoid, when I start from CDB 1.6.1 and I would like to update to CDB 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ddoc Lab for it – http://ddoc.me. Full cycle dev environment for CouchDB, requires no additional backend or scripts.